# Nuxt SSR hydration in dockerized environment

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js app with SSR. It consumes an API that I have built in Django.

On my development environment, everything works fine. But in a dockerized setup, I run into the following problem:

The Axios setup uses a `baseURL` parameter to prepend `http://backend:8000/api`, where `backend` is the name of the service in the `docker-compose` file.

This works fine when I visit a URL directly, and the page is rendered on the server side. However, when I click on any link, and the page is page is now rendered on the client side, Axios requests data from `http://backend:8000`, which obviously is incorrect, as it should be using my website's domain name.

Any thoughts on how I should resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure axios dynamically, depending on the environment (client or server) like this.

Also, your Django API needs an external domain name.

`config.nuxt.js`

```
export default {
  // ...

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.browser ? 'https://api.external-domain.com/api' : 'http://backend-container:8000'
  },

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in NuxtJs v2.15  with Axios module:

In `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://backend:8000/api',
  browserBaseURL: 'http://localhost/api'
  //....
}
```

Also in `docker-compose.yml` file of both API and Frontend projects I setup a network and both with the same name, so their know each other via service name like `http://backend:8000` :

```
networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
```